# unresolved external symbol _CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions

Tags: nuget-package, visual-studio-2022, webview2

My project was successfully built in visual studio 2019. Now I was asked to build in visual studio 2022.

For this project, I need webview2 libraries;
I installed webview2 and windows implementation libraries using NuGet as recommended in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/win32.  These are the same steps that I followed while building on VS19. I even installed the same version on vs2022 also.

Now, I am getting a linker error on vs2022 while building my project.

```
unresolved external symbol _CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions@16 referenced in function blahblah
```

I made sure that the webview2Loader.dll existed. I gave it a try by copying webview2Loader.dll from the vs19 working folder.

Also using dumpbin.exe I made sure that the method in error is exported from webviewLoader.dll

Not sure what else to try? anyone has any idea?

Comment: If you are dynamically linking then you'll need to link your DLL/EXE against webview2.dll.lib (IIRC taking a dependency on the webview2 nuget should do this for you) so you might check if you need to add webview2.dll.lib to the linker options. Or you can statically link if you follow these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/static